# Wicket serving images from directory

Tags: file, resources, wicket

Following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229976/wicket-serving-images-from-file-system), I would like to provide images in a folder as shared resources.

I adapted following lines:

```
getSharedResources().add("images", new FolderContentResource(new  File(this.getServletContext().getResource("/images").getFile())));
```

In a wicket page, a shared resource is accessed as follows:

```
PageParameters params = new PageParameters();
    //params.set(0,"pic1.jpg");
    params.set("fileName","pic1.jpg");
    add(new Image("image", new SharedResourceReference("images"),params));
```

When setting the params with `params.set(0,"pic1.jpg")`, the method `public void respond(Attributes attributes)` is never called. Why do I have to set it via key, value as String pair?

Answer (score 0):

Check this blog article: http://wicketinaction.com/2011/07/wicket-1-5-mounting-resources/. It explains how to do it with a mounted resource reference.